# How do a enable and keep active a div with a hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to keep a div active even if I'm not hovering over it. For example, when I mouse onto a picture it reveals the profile. When I mouse away, it will remain active.

Here is an example of this effect, where the management profiles are displayed: http://www.datastax.com/company#management.

So I used Alex Morrise's example below to create this: http://jsfiddle.net/44jQa/49/

I want the images to have an opacity of 0.5 when the document loads. The opacity should change to 1 when I hover over it. And then back to 0.5 when I move off. I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#.lrow > img").css("opacity", 0.5);

function showPart(id) {
    $('#content .part' + id).fadeIn('400').addClass('show');
}

$('.lrow ').hover(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(this).find('img').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 500);
    if ($('.show').length == 0) {
        showPart(id);
    } else {
        $('.show').removeClass('show').fadeOut('400', function () {
            showPart(id);
        });
    }
}, $(this).find('img').animate({
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 500););
```

Comment: have a look at jquerys `.hover()`

Comment: I agree with @supersize. Take a look at the API and show some code with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding another answer, because your revision is practically a different question. Your fiddle had several issues, including syntax errors. I updated it with the functionality you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/44jQa/51/

You should use this instead of animate:

```
$(this).find('img').fadeTo(400,'.5');
```

Another issue is that this code is probably not cross-browser compatible. But it should give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: thanks! Do you have suggestions on how to make it more compatible? Also, how are the images initialized so that the initial opacity is less than 1?

Comment: The initialization is in the css. Also, one suggestion is to use "filter:opacity(alpha=50)" in addition to "opacity:.5" for cross-browser compatibility.